# YouTrack: Suppress email notifications for some field

Tags: youtrack

I would like to prevent email notifications for a particular field in a project for all users.  I suspect that this would be done via the [Manage Project Notifications](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/Project-Notification-Templates.html) page but cannot figure out what I need to do.  Can anyone provide me with any guidance?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-76359/Suppress-email-notifications-for-some-field#focus=Comments-27-7970666.0-0